# Visual FoxPro DB stored procedure call to Windows service

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-foxpro

I need to use a DB trigger in a FoxPro database on a 2003 server to trigger a stored procedure to call a window service of my design so I can access another SQL Server. Can you think of an idea of how to extend the call from the stored procedure to a Window service?

VFP trigger calls the stored procedure `UpdateTable`:

```
FUNCTION UpdateTable
LPARAMETERS lcTableName, lnRecordID

   callToWinService(lcTableName, lnRecordID)

RETURN
ENDFUNCTION
```

Clearly I do not know how to pass the data to the Windows service. Last time I did that was a few years ago. Any help would be appreciated

And, yes, I can create a Windows service with VFP code in an EXE file.

Comment: Do you really mean a windows service (a background service running on the OS), or a web service?

Comment: I mean a window service, but a call to an EXE file with parameters would be just as good!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean a Windows service, you can't call it with parameters because presumably it's already running as of Windows start-up.

The Windows service would have to expose some way of handling communications in and out. There are various ways of achieving this, some depending on what technology was used to create the service:

- Sockets
- Named Pipes
- Windows Communication Foundation if it's a .NET service
- Shared Memory
- RPC

If you're calling an EXE with parameters, then those get passed to whatever PRG is set as the main program of your VFP project.

But why are you taking this approach?  Why not just use SQLCONNECT(), SQLEXEC() and so on from within  the trigger?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I was not sure that SQLCONNECT could be issued from a Stored Proocedure...  So, I will try it and see...  Sounds great...